# What is the original inspiration for the use of the blue card in the "Clericus Cup" football association?

Tags: rules, football, trivia, officiating

The [Clericus Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clericus_Cup) is a football association of [Roman Colleges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Colleges) and seminaries in and around Rome. This new "league" was stated in 2007 with the encouragement of the Vatican and [Cardinal Bertone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarcisio_Bertone) in particular. What is interesting is the use of the blue card instead of the now standard yellow and red cards. Can anyone tell me what was the original inspiration of this usage or at least point me into the right direction to follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In  Clericus Cup the blue card is show in those situations [(see art 6)](http://www.clericuscup.it/Index.aspx?idmenu=3595):

- tripping, withholding or other foul on an opponent who is going to score a goal;
- voluntary stopping the ball with arm on a direct goal shot;
- voluntary stopping the ball with arm, including the goalkeeper if outside the box, on opponent going to score a goal

A player who receives a blue card is suspended from the match for 5 minutes.

[Italian CSI](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centro_Sportivo_Italiano) (alternative organisation to the most important and official FISG) has organized in 2007 the first Clericus Cup and also tested the blue card for the first time (in addition to the traditional red and yellow ones).

The idea was probably "copied" from ice hockey's temporary ban and is applied to unsportsmanlike fouls.